# How do I select a range containing values greater than specified number?

Tags: vba, range

I have some vba code that I am having trouble with.

Within the range B1:B32, the value equals column A only when its value > 5, otherwise I set it to zero. This part is already set up in excel.

I then want to select only those cells in column B whose value is not equal to 0. 
When I try to run the code below to select the cells I want, I recieve the message 'Application-defined or object-defined error'
 I am fairly new to VBA, so this question may appear very basic to some of you.

Code is below:

```
Sub rangeselect()
    Range("B1").Select
    Dim i As integer

    For i = 1 To 32
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
            Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(i - 1, 2)).Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Appreciate any advice,
thanks

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose of selecting these cells? Are they to be copied somewhere else?

Comment: yes, they are to be copied to another file to be loaded into a software package. But I first need to selec them. The non zero cells will be in a consecutive range, so there wont be any isolated cells with a value of zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still requires some error handling in case all values are zero, but for a start this should do:

```
Sub rangeselect()
  Dim my_range As Range
  For Each cell In Range("B1:B32")
    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        If my_range Is Nothing Then
            Set my_range = cell
        Else
            Set my_range = Union(my_range, cell)
        End If
    End If
  Next
  my_range.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, that works. Fortunately, with the data I am dealing with, it is not possible for all values to be zero, so I dont have to worry about that case.